# Dockerize ASP.NET Core with ReactJS project

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker

I'm new with Docker and I want to dockerize a project created with `ASP.NET Core with ReactJS` template from Visual Studio. My Docker file is looking like this, based on the guide in [Quickstart: Use Docker with a React Single-page App in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-tools-react?view=vs-2022):

```
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y libpng-dev libjpeg-dev curl libxi6 build-essential libgl1-mesa-glx
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y libpng-dev libjpeg-dev curl libxi6 build-essential libgl1-mesa-glx
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["SampleWeb/SampleWeb.csproj", "SampleWeb/"]
RUN dotnet restore "SampleWeb/SampleWeb.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/SampleWeb"
RUN dotnet build "SampleWeb.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SampleWeb.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SampleWeb.dll"]
```

However, while the web page can be debugged using Docker as profile, in order for it to be successful I need to have a command prompt run **npm run start** at `SampleWeb/ClientApp` directory before that. Is there anyway that I can run this command in the container when the project start debugging? Is there any command that can be added in Dockerfile, or project startup configurations that can help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: The `npm run start` command is used when you want to run the React app outside the container for debugging purposes. Your Dockerfile, as shown, should use Kestrel to serve the React files, so there's no need to use npm.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute multiple commands on container startup, you could use e.g. a `start.sh` bash script, which contains those commands:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

(cd SampleWeb/ClientApp; npm run start)
dotnet SampleWeb.dll
```

Then, change your Dockerfile accordingly:

```
ADD start.sh /
RUN chmod +x /start.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./start.sh"]
```